# window.onerror not being fired in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, runtime-error, onerror

I have placed this code on a cordova app:

```
window.onerror = function(error, script, line, column) {
    // code here
}
```

It triggers the `Uncaught Reference Error`s, but that's the only error that's triggered on Android devices.

Should I add something else?

Comment: How are you outputting your exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I feel a little dumb.

When I was testing and it didn't work, I was doing this from Chrome and using GapDebug.

Well. Since the issues were being forced from the Chrome console, the `window.onerror` seemed not to be on scope, so it was not being called. When I simply broke the app from the code itself (instead of doing so from the console), it did work like a charm.

This is just a warning for the next ones dealing with this!